# How to tell if a point is located on a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$P(-3,4,-5)$ and the plane is $(1,-5,6)+s(2,1,3)+t(1,7,1)$

How exactly do I go about with this? I believe that I'm supposed to put the plane in parametric form (see below), then substitute the $x,y,z$ of the point into it? Where do I go from there? Any help is greatly appreciated.
$$\begin{align*}
x&=1+2s+t\\
y&=-5+s+7t\\
z&=6+3s+t
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to work out the cross product of the coplanar vectors $(2,1,3)$ and $(1,7,1)$ and see if this is perpendicular to the vector joining $(-3,4,-5)$ and $(1,-5,6)$ using dot product.

If they are perpendicular then this point lies on the plane.

Answer (score -1):

you must solve the system
$$-3=1+2s+t$$
$$4=-5+s+7t$$
$$-5=6+3s+t$$
for $s$ and $t$

Comment: Nominally, this is not even true, there are (better) alternatives to solving this system.

Comment: Either this is not true (what i had written) or  the method is not true which i have used,but both is true, please refer in an Algebra book.

Comment: Rather than making ridiculous requests, please **read what I wrote** and try to understand it. Hint: you wrote that the OP **must** solve a system, must they, really? If there are other ways to solve this, then they must not. All in all, what a bad example you are giving as a teacher...